# Can I use component inside another component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Something like this

```
<app-component1>
   <app-component2></app-component2>
</app-component1>
```

I did't find about it in Angular docs. When I use component in component, it shows nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `<ng-content></ng-content>` in the template file for `<app-component1>` where you wish to include `<app-component2></app-component2>`.

For example, below could be the HTML file for the component1:-

```
<div>
  <ng-content></ng-content> <!-- component 2 inserted here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Glad, it helped.

Comment: I will do after 7 minutes :) stackoverflow dont allow

Answer (score -1):

Yes, You can nesting component

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   directives: [MyChildComponent]
   template: '<div><ChildComponent></ChildComponent></div>'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

---

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ChildComponent',
   template: '<h2>Child component</h2>'
})
export class MyChildComponent {}
```

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/quickstart/nesting-components-and-inputs/